# Sort the numbers in wpf

Tags: wpf, sorting

How do I sort the numbers in a column in gridview?

XAML:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="No." Width="40" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=No}">
 </GridViewColumn>
```

Is OrderByDescending working here? Or needed any function?....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article.
Basically you change the datasource of your grid to a `CollectionView`. Which in turn supports pagination, sorting and other fancy stuff.